# How to pass " # " in url of django site

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I have site with django as backend and a url pattern like this in my urls.py file.

```
path('api/getnews/home/post/<str:titleInUrl>', getnews.getSpecificHomeNews , name='getspecificHomenews') ,
```

Now when I pass Normal Strings in my url like this, things go well:

```
api/getnews/home/post/Petrol,%20diesel%20prices%20are%20rising%20but%20why%20govt%20does%20not%20look%20worried
```

But when I pass anything with `'#'` symbol in it, python makes it a comment:

```
api/getnews/home/post/#MeToo:%20What%20Priya%20Ramani%20said%20after%20acquittal%20in%20MJ%20Akbar%20defamation%20case
```

I am not able to get my string after the `#` symbol.

Comment: It will not work... `#` is used to point to a specific id in the html. You cannot have it in the url. If you want it to mean `#` you can replace it by its URL encoding `%23`.

Comment: There are two things wrong here: 1. Python will not interpret `#` as the beginning of a comment if it occurs in a string, but somehow that example is not a string and 2. Everything after an unquoted `#` in a URL is a "fragment" and handled locally. It will never be sent to Django.